# Как назвать сочетание «время, оно»?

Tags: пунктуация

> То есть ссылка на отсутствие времени. Но ведь ***время, оно*** всегда
>   есть. Вопрос в том, на что мы его тратим?

Первое — о выделенном. И второе: всё ли здесь с пунктуацией как надо?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется **именительный темы** http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63

При именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится **тире**: **Дорога в дождь — она не сладость,** дорога в дождь — она беда (Евт.).

Примечание. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание **с запятой:** **Врач, он** ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.);

Comment: Это структура    в к л ю ч а е т    в себя именительный темы?

Comment: Это синтаксическая структура с именительным темы. Именительный темы - это обычно  сущ. в И.п. , в данном случае это слово "время." Во второй части предложения (или уже в другом предложении)  это слово заменяется личным местоимением. У Розенталя: Первая часть, находящаяся в начале предложения или текста и выраженная, как правило, формой И.п существительного либо словосочетанием во главе с этой формой (именительный темы, или именительный представления), называет лицо, предмет, явление, которое во второй части (в последующем тексте) получает другое обозначение в форме местоимения:

Answer (score 3):

> И второе: всё ли здесь с пунктуацией как надо?

**В примере - все нормально. И ответы вам дали по существу.**
Но вы уверены, что правильно определили интересующую вас конструкцию?
Извините, что домысливаю, но допускаю, что вопрос касался сочетания "время оно" (без запятой), имеющего совершенно другой смысл. Тогда ни о каком именительном темы или чем-то подобном тут и речи быть не может.

До совсем недавнего времени был употребителен оборот "время **о**но", он и сейчас еще не устарел окончательно.

Значение "то время", обычно в смысле "то еще время","очень давнее" или, реже, "очень плохое". Форма множественного числа "времена оны" и сейчас еще в ходу.

> Через некоторое время оно, было совсем мокрым. [Сергей Довлатов. Дорога > в новую квартиру (1987)]
>
> Первая ― во время оно здесь существовал крупнейший античный порт,
>   отсюда вывозили в Италию зерно (найдена обширная посвятительная
>   надпись Посейдону, разрыты остатки амфитеатра, работает городской
>   музей). [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)]
>
> Во время оно я пробыл там три года старшим научным сотрудником и
>   делал всё, что мне поручали: ездил в экспедиции и командировки,
>   разрывал курганы, описывал древние черепки, диктовал старенькой,
>   дряхленькой машинистке текстовки ко всем вещам мира, неосторожно
>   попавшим в музей, от николаевской копейки до летучей собаки с Яванских
>   островов, делал ещё сотню дел, больших и малых, нужных и ненужных, и в
>   музее меня помнили . [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 1
>   (1964)]
>
> Отец его из Сибири, говорят, во время оно в мороженых осетрах два пуда
>   ассигнаций вывез, и не совсем, будто, тут ладное было― ну, да
>   ведь деньги не меченые. [Е. И. Замятин. Русь (1923)]

(цитаты из Нацкорпуса)

Откуда оно такое взялось, да еще совпало с современным личным местоимением,  в двух словах не расскажешь. Попробую кратко объяснить хотя бы суть.

"Оно" - здесь идиомизированная форма среднего рода старославянского указательного (или указательно-притяжательного) местоимения *"ОН"* - тот, такой.

Исторически, на самых ранних стадиях существования древнеславянского языка, эти местоимения имели полную парадигму склонений и две формы - полную и краткую, три числа (единственное, двойственное и множественное). Краткая и полная формы имели функционально и семантически различную нагрузку, в частности они до некоторой степени играли роль постфиксного неопределенного и определенного артикля соответственно.

Полные формы слонялись как современные прилагательные, краткие - как существительные:

И он, она, оно, оны, оный, оная, оное, оные 
Р она, оны, она, онов/он, оного, оной, оного, оных
(и т. д. двойственное число опускаю)

Очень приблизительно:
"человѣкъ онъ" - "некоторый "тот" человек"
"человѣкъ оный" - "именно тот человек"
"человѣка она" - "некоторого "того" человека"
"человѣка оного" - "именно того человека"

"Время оно" - "неконкретное то время"

Кроме того существовали и собственно личные местоимения:

И: (Й)И, Я, Е, (ЙЫ)  - (современные он, она, оно, они - форма множественного числа гипотетическая)
Р: его, ея, его, их 
и т. д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впоследствии эти местоимения ОН, ОНО, ОНА вышли из употребления как указательные, но при этом частично заменили собой личные И, Я, Е (в именительном падеже, породив современную весьма своеобразную парадигму склонения личных местоимений), частично (особенно полные формы) сохранились как архаизированные или идиомизированные формы.

В сочетании "время оно" мы имеем как раз пример последнего случая.

Comment: В примере всё нормально. И ответы даны по существу. «Время оно» заслуживает отдельного разговора. Спасибо, Мимоходов!

Comment: @shampar я просто не мог предположить, что у вас вызовет какое-то затруднение "время, оно". Оборот-то вполне обычный.

Comment: Я хотел подтверждения отнесения связки к конкретной из сигментированных конструкций. Потом определился. А пунктуация здесь непринципиальна, вплоть до многоточия (время... оно).