# «Тело(,) оно глупо, зато душа сильна»: нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, пословицы, именительный-темы

Как я понимаю, в приведенном предложении есть именительный темы, поэтому указанная запятая нужна. Верно ли это?

> Тело(,) оно глупо, зато душа сильна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже думаю, что это **именительный темы.**  Чтобы считать эту фигуру неправомерным дублированием и ошибкой, надо видеть весь текст, по одному предложению судить сложно.

Пример из Нацкорпуса: ***А тело, оно по привычке ищет дорогу в родную землю.*** [Герман Садулаев. Таблетка (2008)]

Еще на эту же тему: *Как ни близко тело, оно все-таки чужое, только душа своя.* [Л. Н. Толстой. Путь жизни (1910)]

Вполне возможно записать эту мысль так: *Тело, оно все-таки чужое, только душа своя.*

**Отрывок из книги Чучмай Ю. В.  "Ведьмы танцуют в огне":**

– А ты чего мрачный такой?

– Я сегодня за мясом ходил в лавку, – монотонно начал Готфрид ...И там была девушка. Знаешь, такая красивая, что я даже засмотрелся. Хотелось побольше ей полюбоваться, но она ушла, а я так ничего и не смог сказать. Жалко, ведь такая красивая…

– Да все они такие… Красивые вроде, а в душу загляни – сущие ведьмы, – отмахнулся Дитрих, громко жуя...

Готфрид только вздохнул.

– Мне, вон, тоже многие нравятся, – продолжал Дитрих. – Но я себя в руках держу, и тебе учиться надо. **Тело () оно глупо, зато душа сильна.** **А особенно у слуг божьих...**

Комментарий

Из этого отрывка видно, **для чего применяется именительный темы.** Фактически это краткая запись следующего предложения: Если слушать тело (говорить о теле и т.д.), то оно глупо, зато душа сильна.

Без именительного темы логический переход к следующему высказыванию героя был бы неясен.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая-то  на месте, но вот всё предложение выглядит просторечно.

Я не думаю, что это именительный темы, т.е. представление темы, которая будет развёрнута в остальном высказывании. Такие предложения не являются грамматической нормой.

Грамма.ру  приводит пример ошибки: **Местоименное дублирование подлежащего:** "Дети, сидящие на старой опрокинутой вверх килем лодке, они ждут своего отца".    http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=10.10

Такое употребление местоимения оправдано в ораторской и поэтической речи: Весь облик Грузии любимой, он стал другим в сознаньи жить. (Н. Тихонов)

В других случаях такое явление наблюдается в разговорном языке, просторечии, что не является литературной нормой. Часто приходится слышать, как дикторы радио и телевидения допускают языковую небрежность, например: Депутаты Госдумы, они приняли закон в третьем чтении. Наш национальный парк “Куршская коса”… он требует к себе постоянного внимания ученых и рядовых работников. Евгений Онегин, он был представлен дворянской молодежи. Или еще пример из недавнего выступления премьер-министра М. Касьяна перед журналистами: “Соответствующие службы, они, конечно, разберутся…”
https://vuzlit.ru/941437/upotreblenie_lichnyh_mestoimeniy

Так что если это поэтическая речь, то поэтам "закон не писан", у них везде экспрессия, только здесь я что-то и экспрессии особой не вижу.

Comment: Это из романа (повести?); может, там был подходящий контекст, уже не помню.

Comment: https://books.google.ee/books?id=UpjGtOPP7_oC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=k5xJCIPUeA&sig=SsTurwCPXiB2PwhvNgbVTviZrSg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKwurv_brfAhVii8MKHYn8AX4Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE&f=false Ю. Чучмай. Ведьмы танцуют в огне. Не отсюда?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова блестяще, Ватсон! :)

Comment: Ой, не перехвали́те, — возгорДЮсь.

Comment: Я прочитала, спасибо Римме, тогда всё в порядке, здесь речь героя, разговорный синтаксис вполне на месте.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен, это именительный темы. В таких случаях ставят запятую или тире. Посмотрите также ответы [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441790/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE/441792#441792) и [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445556/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F/445558#445558).

Answer (score 0):

> Подлежащее, оно не нуждается в уточнении местоимением.

Русский язык. Антипримеры